# Grails 2 - Too many Ajax calls will invalidate user sesssion

Tags: ajax, grails-2.0, invalidation

*update: sorry, i didn't give a context. I'm using Grails 2.1.2 with the spring security plugin installed. Js lib -> jQuery (latest)

I have a page that submits lots of synchronous ajax calls (not my design, sorry). After the 25th call i see from firebug that i start getting http 302 status, then the handler for ajax calls when there's no user session is called (loing/authAjax in my case). My particular handler sends an http 401. In any case why is the session expiring? This happens only when i submit tons of *synchronous* ajax calls. Is there any limit to the number of ajax calls? Is it documented anywhere? Making async calls is not an option in this case because these ajax calls make db updates on the same table and that would result in a hibernate lock exception.

I'm not asking for a fix, i know how to fix this (by doing one single ajax call). What i'm asking is why the session is being invalidated? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the cache setting to false in your calls with jQuery ?
302 means you're getting data from the browser cache instead of the server.
Hope this help....